# Retrieve value of a title tag

Tags: d3.js

I'm using the library d3 to draw a world.
Using this library my html page contains a svg tag. this has many child (the tags "path"), for each of this tag i want to recover the value of "title tag" but i can't.
This is the DOM:

```
---svg
     ---path
        ---title
               Italy
     ---path
        ---title
               France
      ---path
```

This is my code:

```
var title = $('title');
alert(title.length); //246
for(var i =0; i<title.length;i++){
  alert(title[i]); 
  //i want to retrieve Italy,France... 
  //but the alert return [object HTML TitleElement]
}
```

How can i retrive the value of tag?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `d3.selectAll("title").each(function(d) { return d.attr("text"); })`?

Comment: doesn't work, this is the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of undefined

Comment: Oh sorry, this should have been `d3.select(this).attr("text")`.

Comment: doesn't work! Sorry but this is refer to document?

Comment: This would be inside the `.each` function. And yes, I should think before typing. Next try -- `d3.select(this).text()`.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer given the number of tries it took me to work it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the titles thusly:

```
d3.selectAll("title").each(function() { return d3.select(this).text(); });
```